# WCF CallBack in Production Environment

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

I know this is going to sound stupid - but we've spent close to 4 weeks trying to implement a WCF callback system (**Subscription Service**), but to no avail.

*Can anyone verify that they have successfully got this working in a multiple client production environment?*

All the examples I've come across work on localhost but in production fails miserably.

The specific problem is that subscriptions and un-subscriptions work perfectly, up until the client is closed and re-opened at which point; multiple CallBacks are made or the Publish Method times out.

**Again, can anyone confirm they have this working, or perhaps direct me to some documentation that provides a real-world PROVEN example.**

Background info on my existing configuration found here:
[WCF to WCF Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548722/wcf-to-wcf-communication/17549925#17549925)

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is too indefinite. There may be many reasons of this - type of hostings, security settings, firewalls. You should provide some more details of your problem, like client and service configurations.

Comment: I can say that WCF callbacks work fine for me in systems distributed acress multiple hosts. I'm basically using one-way methods in callback contracts and net.tcp endpoints.

Comment: Its probably not the best solution, but in our environment (we have duplex communication, but it does not metter) - during users notifications for subscribers list, we are handling the callback notification failure - and removing such subscriber from the list.

Comment: Yeah I know it's indefinite - and it's for the vastness of the subject and it's permutations that I did not put code or examples, just the overview. My main aim by my question is to know if this really works, and if there are resources on the net that actually give me a REAL WORLD code sample.